# How to redirect page to some other page if Database Error Occurs

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, redirect

I have applied composite Primary key on a table which returns error message if the Primary Key constraint fails, 
So whenever user enters the  duplicate rows the programs throws the following error message.

```
Duplicate entry '43-15' for key 'uk_sid_coursid'
```

I want to skip this error message, I want page to redirect to another page `myerror.php` where user can go back and update the records. I have use `if-else` condition, but still its giving me the same error message. Below is my code,Kindly review it.

> **MODEL**

```
    public function student_marks_fill($student_id, $semester_course_id)
    {
        $data= array(
            "StudentId"=> $student_id,
            "SemisterCourseId"=>$semester_course_id
        );

        if($this->db->insert('student_marks', $data))
        {
            return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
                }

        }
```

> **Controller**

```
            if($this->loginmodel->student_marks_fill($id, $semesterCourseId))
            {
                $this->load->view('admin');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->load->view('admin');
                    }

            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **db_debug** - TRUE/FALSE (boolean) - Whether database errors should be
>   displayed.

Set `db_debug` as `FALSE` in `config/database.php`

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

**Documentation:** http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html